# How do I use Renderer2 to create an element as a child?

Tags: angular

**Angular: Content Projection from an Attribute Directive**

I'd like to create a new element inside a component using an attribute directive (for now, let's call it: 'insertEditButton'):

```
<my-component insertEditButton></my-component>
<another-component insertEditButton></another-component>
<div insertEditButton></div>
```

I've looked at using Renderer2(https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Renderer2-class.html) but it is not clear in the docs how to use 
`createElement(name: string, namespace?: string) : any`

I was hoping someone can provide me with an example of how to use Renderer2's createElement method in an attribute-directive. Or, what other solutions can I consider?

Comment: What do you want this directive to do?

Answer (score 0):

**Example:**

*Component 1:*

```
@Component({
    selector: '[my-component1]',
    template: `
        <span>hello there</span>
    `
})
export class myComponent1 {}
```

*Component 2:*

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component2',
    template: `
        <p my-component1></p>
    `
})
export class myComponent2 implements OnInit {}
```

Output:

```
<p><span>hello there</span></p>
```

The hey is in the selector. When you declare the selector like this:

```
selector: 'my-component1'
```

Then you 'use' this component like this: `<my-component1>`, as a `tag`.

If you declare it like this:

```
selector: '[my-component1]'
```

Then you 'use' this component like this: `<tag my-component1>`, as a tag's `attribute`.

Comment: Thank you. That was my first solution actually. But, the goal is to do:`<my-component myAttrDirective/>`. Can't apply a component attribute selector into a component (yes, works in a tag.) That is why we are looking into an attribute-directive.